# Bluetooth IsConnected()

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm doing an Bluetooth application which I connect any device and do some work. I have lots of activities. I do all connection stuff in the `BlutoothConnectionService.java` class. In my `BondedDevicesActivity` I click a device that I would like to connect. Then service works and another activity is opened. Then I click some buttons which opens another activities. In all activity I'm sending some information via bluetooth. Thus whenever I open another activity I use `BlutoothConnectionService.java` class. Problem is in this class, it always trying to connect to device. I would like that once it is connected, it never tries it again until connection is dead. But I couldn't figure out how to make that. I know there is a method called `isConnected()` but I don't know where to put it in the service class. Here is my code of service:

```
public class BluetoothConnectionService {
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionSrvc";
private static final UUID connectionUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
Context ctx;
private ConnectThread connectThread;
private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
private UUID deviceUUID;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private ConnectedThread connectedThread;
String incomingMessage;

public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context, BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    ctx = context;
    startClient(device, uuid);
}

public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
    Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");
    connectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
    connectThread.start();
}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
        bluetoothDevice = device;
        deviceUUID = uuid;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "ConnectThread: Run.");
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create RFcommSocket using UUID: " + connectionUUID);
            tmp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Cihaza Bağlanılıyor", "Lütfen Bekleyiniz...", true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Couldn't create RFcommSocket" + e.getMessage());
            showMessage("Cihaza bağlanılamadı, lütfen bağlantınızı kontrol ederek tekrar deneyiniz.");
            AnaEkranActivity.instance.finish();
        }

        if (tmp != null) {
            bluetoothSocket = tmp;
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectionThread connected.");
                connected(bluetoothSocket);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();
                showMessage("Cihaza bağlanılamadı, lütfen bağlantınızı kontrol ederek tekrar deneyiniz.");
                AnaEkranActivity.instance.finish();
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket" + e1.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + connectionUUID);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void connected(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connected: Starting.");
    connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    connectedThread.start();
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");
        bluetoothSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            tmpIn = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        inputStream = tmpIn;
        outputStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int readBytes;

        while (true) {
            try {
                readBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                incomingMessage = new String(readBuffer, 0, readBytes);
                Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                showMessage(incomingMessage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "read: Error reading from inputStream." + e.getMessage());
                showMessage("Connection is dead.");
                AnaEkranActivity.instance.finish();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] writeBytes) {
        String text = new String(writeBytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputStream: " + text);
        try {
            outputStream.write(writeBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to outputStream." + e.getMessage());
            showMessage("Error while writing.");
        }
    }
}

public void write (byte[] out) {
    Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
    connectedThread.write(out);
}

public String read () {
    Log.d(TAG, "read: Read Called.");
    connectedThread.run();
    return incomingMessage;
}

public void showMessage(final String toastMessage) {
    AnaEkranActivity.instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

In android documentation you will get this answer. There we are using same thing in Bluetooth chatting app. Here is the link [Bluetooth chat app](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

Which gives you information about connection. And [this explanation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

will help you to solve this problem. Go through once clearly you will get the solution.

Comment: Unfotunately, I've deeply studied these documentations but there is absolutely nothing useful about my problem.